# Shade density plot to the left of vline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to shade a density plot using a vline as cutoff? For example:

```
df.plot <- data.frame(density=rnorm(100))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.plot, aes(density)) + geom_density() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = -0.25)
```

I tried creating a new variable, but it does not work as I expected

```
df.plot <- df.plot %>% mutate(color=ifelse(density<(-0.25),"red","NULL"))


ggplot(df.plot, aes(density, fill = color, colour = color)) + geom_density() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = -0.25)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that directly with `ggplot`. But you could calculate the density outside of ggplot over the desired range:

```
set.seed(4132)
df.plot <- data.frame(density=rnorm(100))
ds <- density(df.plot$density, from = min(df.plot$density), to = -0.25)
ds_data <- data.frame(x = ds$x, y = ds$y)
```

`density()` estimates the density for the points given in its first argument. The result will contain `x` and `y` values. You can specify the `x`-range you are interested in with `from` and `to`. In order for the density to agree with the one plotted by `ggplot()`, set the ranges to the minimal and maximal value in `df.plot$density`. Here, `to` is set to `-0.25`, because you only want the part of the density curve to the left of your vline. You can then extract the `x` and `y` values with `ds$x` and `ds$y`.

The plot is then created by using the same code as you did, but adding an additional `geom_area()` with the density data that was calculated above:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.plot, aes(density)) + geom_density() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = -0.25) +
  geom_area(data = ds_data, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]