# Conditional fill in a density plot within same group

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I want to create a density plot with ridges where colour is conditional on crossing a certain threshold.

The aim is to illustrate the distribution of earnings while highlighting those over a certain threshold (AUD $1368 per week).  I've provided a bare-bones plot of my attempt below.

```r
ggplot(subset(vic, totalweekslost > 0 & nwe %in% 100:3000), 
       aes(nwe, fill = nwe > 1368)) + 
  geom_density()
```

Instead of just changing the colour of those within a single group in the density plot, it creates a new group on its own scale.

[image: reproduced here]

What I want is for the colour change to be in the same group and a clear cut-point illustrated. I can see what is wrong with my code, but I can't figure out how to create what I'm after.

Comment: There are numerous similar questions floating around. You may wish to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224394/shade-density-plot-to-the-left-of-vline) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516759/fixed-fill-for-different-sections-of-a-density-plot-with-ggplot), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can get the values of `geom_density()` and use `geom_area()`.
Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215748/how-to-shade-part-of-a-density-curve-in-ggplot-with-no-y-axis-data)
This should do the trick:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Build some data
vic = data.frame(totalweekslost = 100:3000, nwe = 100:3000)

#Yours code
df = subset(vic, totalweekslost > 0 & nwe %in% 100:3000 )    

# Creating density plot
p = ggplot(df, 
           aes(x = nwe)
          ) + 
  geom_density()

# Getting the values of plot
d = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

# Building shaded area
p = p +  geom_area(data = subset(d, x>1368), aes(x=x,y=y), fill = "#00AFBB", alpha = 0.5)

plot(p)
```

[image: Here the output plot]

Comment: Great! The link above have another example to this kind of fill.      
You can add an vertical line in the boundary too, just add:

`geom_vline(xintercept = 1368)` .     

Best regards